# Why isn't this printing anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print everything in the list element that comes after the "#" but I keep getting

> "ValueError: '#' is not in list"

even though it's right there and I can see it? What am I doing wrong?

I've done this before a while back using the same index function and it worked back again so I'm really confused.

```
data=["123#4567"]

print (data[data.index("#"):])
```

Comment: `"#"` is not in the list `data`, it's in the string that is in the list `data`.

Comment: `#` is not, by itself, an item in that list.

Comment: Try `print (data[0][data[0].index("#"):])`

Comment: `print (data[0][data[0].index("#") + 1:])`

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to have `data=["123#4567"]` and not just `data="123#4567"`?

Answer (score 2):

## Code

```
data = ['123#4567']
data = [d.split('#')[1] for d in data]
print (data)
```

## Console

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data = ['123#4567']
>>> data = [d.split('#')[1] for d in data]
>>> print (data)
['4567']
```

## Explanation

Since the list contains strings, the variable d is a string. Thus, `d.split('#')[1]` calls the split() method of strings. Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), the first parameter of this method is the string to split by. The method returns the list of strings that result from performing the split, so `[1]` returns the second split string in the result list.

i.e. ['4567']

Comment: I think if someone is new enough to python to have to ask this question, they aren't going to understand this answer without a little bit of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it, but *the way you're using it*, `data` behaves like a nested list:

```
[  # this is a list
    "123#4567"  # this is a string, which sometimes acts like a list
]
```

So when you do `data.index('#')`, python says "okay, there's one element in `data`, it's `"123#4567"`, that isn't `"`, therefore throw an error because I didn't find the element I was looking for".

If you want to split the string or properly find the index, then you need to get *inside* the list and get to the string itself. This can be done either explicitly:

```
data = ["123#4567"]
print(data[0][data[0].index("#"):])  # data[0] holds the string
```

iteratively, if `data` were to hold multiple strings:

```
data = ["123#4567", "987#6543"]
print(elem[elem.index("#"):] for elem in data)  # iterate over every string in data, which would work even if data only contained one string
```

or by just setting `data` to a string in the first place:

```
data = "123#4567"
print(data[data.index("#"):])
```

Comment: if `data` list has multiple items like `data=["123#4567","123#4567", "123#4567"]`